# compiler behaving abnormally c++

Tags: c++

I am using this simple program.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
        int arr[200]={0};
        int i = 200;
        arr[i] = 1;
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

I expect the result to be 200; In my system its showing result as 1.
Can anyone explain the abnormal behavior.

Comment: You went past the bounds of `arr` by 1 (0 - 199) and clobbered `i` which comes next? The compiler is doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: That is one funny UB.

Comment: I changed the sequence I declared my variables. First i and next arr. After this also it is showing the same. at least after changing the sequence should work. As i expect first compiler assigns memory for i and then for arr.

Comment: If you in the future suspect something is wrong with some simple stuff you can always use CompileOnline as a reference. Used it a lot when i started learning c++

Comment: @Guru Read what crashmstr wrote more clearly

Comment: @Guru the order you declare your variables is only loosely correlated with the order the compiler puts them in memory. Since there's no observable effect from reordering them in a well formed program, it's free to put them wherever it wants.

Comment: @Ransom: I never knew It can reoder memory assignments as part of optimization. Thankyou.

Comment: You could try also try allocating the array with `malloc`, so it's not on the stack, and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You allocated an array with 200 elements which gives you indexes 0 through 199.  You set the item at index 200 to be 1, which is beyond the bounds of your array.  C++ is happy to let you stomp whatever memory you want.  You declared `i` right after `arr` and so it literally got allocated on the stack right after `arr` in memory, so you set it to 1 when you went past the end of your array by one element.

You can verify by declaring `i` before `arr` and see what happens.  Or set `i` to 199, which is probably what you meant to do.

Comment: "*C++ is happy to let you stomp whatever memory you want.*" - as long as it belongs to the same process. "*it literally got allocated on the stack right after arr*"- that is compiler dependent, so it happened "most probably".

Comment: @luk32 the restriction of being in the same process is enforced by the OS and CPU memory management, not by C++ itself.

Comment: @Mark Aw. Fair enough. I retract that, my bad.

Comment: Yes, that's all true.  Feel free to edit the answer to improve it.